# Can someone explain the real meaning of とろんと溶け?

Tags: meaning, words, japanese-to-english

I don't know what does とろんと mean here ,and i can only understand 溶け means "something is melting"
Please someone explain to me  ,thank you o/

Comment: I would guess とろん is the adverb.

Comment: It is a variant of [とろり](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%81%A8%E3%82%8D%E3%82%8A/#jn-161870). Essentially it does not add any meaning and the whole phrase just means *melt and/melting*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

とろん(と) is an adverb that is roughly the same as [とろとろ](https://jisho.org/search/%E3%81%A8%E3%82%8D%E3%81%A8%E3%82%8D)(と) or とろりと. It describes how something melts into a semi-solid form. Imagine melting chocolate.

Related: [How are the giongo/gitaigo double form and tto form related (きらきら vs. きらっと)](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/1479/5010)

Comment: As a resident of Toronto, I'm not sure how to feel about this.