# What does どばっと mean in this question?

Tags: meaning, words, definitions

I came across [this question on Japanese Quora](https://jp.quora.com/%E9%A3%9B%E8%A1%8C%E6%A9%9F%E3%81%A7-tomato-juice-without-ice-please%E3%81%A8%E3%81%8A%E9%A1%98%E3%81%84%E3%81%97%E3%81%BE%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F-CA%E3%81%95%E3%82%93%E3%81%8C-no-ice-%E3%81%A8%E8%81%9E%E3%81%8B%E3%82%8C).

I will also post the text of the question in case the link doesn't work:
「飛行機で、tomato juice without ice, pleaseとお願いしました。CAさんが、no ice？と聞かれました。Yes! と答えました。氷をどばっと入れてくださいました。なぜ？」

I more or less understood it but paused when I got to the「どばっと」part. I wasn't able to find anything on jisho.com but when I searched Japanese Google I found [this result on Weblio for synonyms](https://thesaurus.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%A9%E3%81%B0%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A8)

From what I gather it's just a shortening of the onomatopoeia どばどば? Which I understand that and all the other synonyms provided after searching their definitions; it seems to be conveying a very excited or violent pouring/rushing of water or any liquid for that matter if I got it right.

So in this case what would be the meaning in this question? Am I correct in my understanding that the asker is trying to convey that they received a very large amount of ice in their drink? Or not necessarily a large amount, but just a very enthusiastic pouring of ice into their drink?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question means:

> On an airplane, I asked (to a flight atetndant), "Tomato juice without ice, please". The attendant asked me, "No ice?". (I) replied, "Yes!". (Then the attendant) kindly poured a lot of ice! Why was that?

どばっと is not a simple short version of どばどば. For the difference, see: [How are the giongo/gitaigo double form and tto form related (きらきら vs. きらっと)](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/1479/5010) So the idea here is that the attendant put a lot of ice in a short time (but "violent" is an overstatement here).

By saying "Yes", the asker meant he wanted no ice. You can read the following questions for the root cause of this confusion.

- [The reality of answering いいえ to a negative question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/2908/5010)
- [What's the difference between いいえ and English's "no"?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/5144/5010)